# Typed wrong mv command

Tags: linux

Hi i worked on Linux server , and was running this command `mv matter/*/* .`

but instead i have typed this   `mv matter /*/* .`

because of which some errors starts coming on the screen , and then i was not able to login and when we reboot the server its not coming up.

so can you please tell me what this command has done `mv matter /*/* .`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you use code highlighting to show your commands - enter the commands exactly as typed, then hightlight them and click the `{}` editor button or `ctl-k`. That will preserve whitespace and show them exactly as you entered.

Comment: Time to use your backup and/or to reinstall the entire system. Happy New Year :-)

Comment: That's why you shouldn't work as root if it's not absolutely neccesary. Reinstall your system.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out for yourself by inserting an `echo` at the beginning of the command line:

```
echo mv matter /*/* .
```

The expanded command looks like this:

```
mv matter /bin/ash /bin/bash /bin/echo /bin/false [...] /home/yourname [...] .
```

All files and directories from the top-level directories (`echo /*/`) have been moved to this one directory where you executed that command. It's hard to separate them from there, but you can try using a rescue CD:

- move all executable files to `/bin`
- make `/sbin` a symlink to `/bin`
- move all files that look like configuration files to `/etc`

But since you couldn't find out for yourself what the `mv` command was doing exactly, you should rather ask someone who knows to fix it for you. It's a lot of work, though.